# How to fit a LinearLayout according to an Image?

Tags: android, xml, layout

How to fit a LinearLayout to an Image? (or any alternative) 
I need to keep the ratio of the image to write in (over) windows of this instrument and press buttons

Here is the preview:

[preview with wanted layouts in green and red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohM2L.jpg)

The image has the correct ratio, I would like a LinearLayout to take the weight and the width of the Image (I drawed it as a green boxe on the Image), then I will be able to place my other items over the image (in red boxes I drawed)

And here is the code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="myapp.fragments.myfragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pca"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it is a better idea to use a GridView

Comment: I just worked on your idea, the problem is the same: image doesn't keep ratio or gridView doesn't take the good height (height of the image)
thx anyway ;)